WSO2 Carbon: ClassNotFoundException for custom message builder with application/problem+json content type
I'm encountering an issue while configuring custom message builders and formatters in WSO2 Integration Studio (or WSO2 Carbon). I have followed the steps to add a custom message builder (org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder) and formatter (org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter) for handling application/problem+json content type in both deployment.toml and axis2.xml.
After making these configurations and restarting the server, I'm facing the following error:
`WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while loading the Axis configuration from /path/to/axis2.xml
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: A ClassNotFoundException error occurred while validating the message builder org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v85

`
Steps Token:

Added the following configurations to deployment.toml:

Steps Token:
[[custom_message_formatters]]
class = "org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter"
content_type = "application/problem+json"

[[custom_message_builders]]
class = "org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder"
content_type = "application/problem+json"



Updated axis2.xml to include references to the custom message builder and formatter:

<messageBuilders>
    <builder contentType="application/problem+json" class="org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
    <!-- Other message builders -->
</messageBuilders>
<messageFormatters>
    <formatter contentType="application/problem+json" class="org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
    <!-- Other message formatters -->
</messageFormatters>


Error Details:

Error Message: WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while loading the Axis configuration from /path/to/axis2.xml
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: A ClassNotFoundException error occurred while validating the message builder
org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v85


Integration studio equipped with embedded micro integrator product distribution. Message builder and formatter package paths slightly different with the EI package paths. You can refer to the default configuration in the axis2 for more information.

Your class names are wrong. Try setting the following. The correct builder class is the below. Also don't change the axis2.xml add the below to delpoyment.toml
[[custom_message_formatters]]
class = "org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter"
content_type = "application/problem+json"

[[custom_message_builders]]
class = "org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder"
content_type = "application/problem+json"

